# Apache Ignite - uanable to access remote nodes through REST API

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I'm configured a node locally and can access via http://localhost:47100/ignite however when i execute a command like getting the node version to try read and write to a cache i get the following response ÿ|h2—Ÿ™Lá·šŠHpT«Ã

My setup is very basic - I have a single Ignite node running on a Windows machine. The node is using one of the sample cache examples when  starting the node.

Should i be using a separate port or do i need to enable REST API?

Answer (score 3):

1. Enter into your IGNITE_HOME folder
2. Copy folder IGNITE_HOME/lib/optional/ignite-rest-http into IGNITE_HOME/lib
3. Start-up one node

```
bin/ignite.sh -i 
or
bin/ignite.bat -i
```

4. Check with

   ```
   netstat -tna
   ```

   ... listening port on 8080
5. Check on your browser http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=version

Answer (score 2):

Ports `47100` and `47500` are used by Ignite for internal communication and discovery. By default REST API (when enabled) binds to port `8080`.

If you need to change the port used for HTTP REST, you can do it by either setting `IGNITE_JETTY_PORT` system property or by providing a path to the Jetty configuration file in ConnectorConfiguration object which is set to IgniteConfiguration:

```
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="connectorConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorConfiguration">
            <property name="jettyPath" value="/path/to/jetty/configuration.xml"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
...
```

Note that the system property overrides the port value set in Jetty XML configuration.